# AdWords v201601 guide migration

Tags: migration, google-ads-api

To make long story short : I'am looking for the AdWords migration guide v201601, the link below is down, and i can't find any archive of this document on the web.

https://developers.google.com/adwords/api/docs/guides/migration/v201601

A little more explanation : My client currently using the version 201509 which is expired since June 21 2016. I have to use a new version of the API but there is no way to find the appropriate documentation throught internet.

**A little more explanation. (EDIT)**

My customer had an application with the AdWords API v201509 and i have to make it compliant with the AdWords API v201607,
To achieve my work i need to check all the modification made since the AdWords API v201509 releasing,

I have already checked these documents,

Migration Guide (v201607)

Migration Guide (v201605)

Migration Guide (v201603)

But i don't have the migration Guide v201601,

Note : Thank to stakcoevrfolw, i can't post too links because "You need at least 10 reputation to post more than 2 links."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no use in migrating to `v201601` as that version has also been sunset on August 27, 2016.

The lowest version you can upgrade to is `v201603`, but I'd really recommend you to go directly to `v201607` as the former one will be sunset in around a month.

[e]: The [release notes](https://developers.google.com/adwords/api/docs/reference/#v201601) for `v201601` are still online and give a good overview the changes.